# javascript compare value of a certain key in all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I an array of objects like this:

```
var items=
[
    {
        name: 'blah',
        country: 'Foos'
    },
    {
        name: 'foo',
        country: 'Foos'
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        country: 'Foos'
    },
    {
        name: 'baz',
        country: 'Foos'
    }
];
```

I want to compare the values for all the `country` keys and return true/false if they are all the same value.
The array could be of any length, sometimes, only one object and sometimes several dozen.

How can i compare it using ecma6 practices **preferably**?

### update:

the challenge is that i don't know what the `keyValue` will be each time, i just want to check if it is the same across all objects in that array.

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Kind of goes with the previous two comments, but what "ecma6 practices" are you looking for? Is there some reason you don't like for loops (which unless I'm horribly mistaken was not removed from the spec and therefore "ecma6 practices").

Comment: @scrappedcola i updated the question, preferably with ecma6.

Comment: Get the value of the first element, then use `every` to compare it to other values. `every` will return false on the first non-match. There is no need to check every element in the array after you found one error.

Comment: So you want to compare the values of `country`, not `name`, and return `true` if they are all equal?

Comment: @RaphaMex yeh that is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the value of the first element, then use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to compare it to other values.[every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will return false on the first non-match. There is no need to check every element in the array after you found ONE that doesn't match.

```js
 let list =
[
    { name: 'foo', country: 'Foos' },
    { name: 'bar', country: 'Foos' },
    { name: 'baz', country: 'Foos' }
];


function isCountryTheSameInAllObjects(list) {
  if (!(list && list.length)) return true; // If there is no list, or if it is empty, they are all the same, aren't they?
  let compare = list[0].country;
  return list.every( item => item.country === compare);
}

console.log('is Country same?', isCountryTheSameInAllObjects(list));
```

If you want to compare every key in every object:

```js
let list =
[
    { name: 'foo', country: 'Foos' },
    { name: 'bar', country: 'Foos' },
    { name: 'baz', country: 'Foos' }
];

function isAllKeysTheSameInEveryObject(list) {
  if (!(list && list.length)) return true; // If there is no list, or if it is empty, they are all the same, aren't they?
  let compare = list[0];
  let sourceKeys = compare && Object.keys(compare);
  return list.every( item => {
    if ( compare ) {
      if (!item) return false;
      let itemKeys = Object.keys(item);
      // If key lenghs different, then it is not same.
      if ( sourceKeys.length != itemKeys.length) return false;
      // make sure all keys are the same.
      if ( !sourceKeys.every( key => itemKeys.indexOf(key) >= 0 )) return false;
      // compare keys
      return sourceKeys.every( key => compare[key] === item[key] );
    } else {
      // If compare is an object, but not item, then it is false.
      if (item) return false;
    }
  })
}

console.log('is all keys same?', isAllKeysTheSameInEveryObject(list));
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (!(list && list.length)) return false;` ?

Comment: It depends on your definition... if there are no object in there, are they all the same or all different?

Comment: it is possible that there is no object inside the array, or there is one, or multiple, and it is possible that the values for the country key be the same or different. every scenario is open

Comment: it is empty or nothing in there, it should return false, because our comparison is on the country key, if it doesn't exist, then it is by definition false! we need to compare and then return true only if they are the same

Comment: If you want to return false, null, NaN or something else if the list is empty, then you are free to change that in your code. You didn't specify that in your question. And considering what a small edit that is to your code, is that really something you would like to complain about?

Answer (score 1):

Can do it this way as well:

```js
var items = [{
        name: 'blah',
        country: 'Foos'
    },
    {
        name: 'foo',
        country: 'Foos'
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        country: 'Foos'
    },
    {
        name: 'baz',
        country: 'Foos'
    }
];

function compareCountries(items) {
    for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].country !== items[0].country) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
alert(compareCountries(items));
```

Comment: This is the very basic way of doing it, though I like how @brk have implemented it!

Comment: brks version doesn't work and doesn't short-circuit . Suggestions for your: Put `items` as a parameter to the function `compareCountries(items)`, and start comparing from element index 1. (if item[0].country !== item[0].country, then it is weird... or NaN)

Comment: I didn't passed items as the items array was on the same page. Thanks though. And it does work have you checked it. 0 index is the first object to be compared

Comment: What I suggested was to change `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)` to `for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++)`. There is no need to check it with itself.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks

Comment: And change `function compareCountries()`to `function compareCountries(items)`. That way your function don't use a global variable, but the variable that you send to it when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this way

First get the first item's country, then search for not equals in items

```
function allSame(items){
    let firstItemCountry = items[0] && items[0].country;
    return !items.find(item => item.country !== firstItemCountry) && true;
}
console.log(allSame(items));
```